# Best way to get the list of XML files

Tags: linq, vb.net

I'm a newbie in the use of `LinqToXml` and I wonder if I can improve this snippet.

```
 Shared Function GetListByType(ByVal intIndex As Integer) As List(Of FileInfo)

            Dim strWorkingPath As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(GetWorkspaceDir)
            Dim lstAllFiles As FileInfo() = strWorkingPath.GetFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Dim lstFiltredList As New List(Of FileInfo)
            Dim xelement As XElement
            Dim contratTypeIndex As String
            Dim contratVersion As Integer

            For Each fic In lstAllFiles
                xelement = xelement.Load(fic.FullName)
                contratTypeIndex = xelement.Element("TypeIndex").Value
                contratVersion = xelement.Element("Version").Value
                If (contratTypeIndex = intIndex.ToString And contratVersion = 0) Then
                    lstFiltredList.Add(fic)
                End If
            Next

            Return lstFiltredList.Distinct.ToList

        End Function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option Strict**

You should always set [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) = On.

**Short circuit evaluation**

You should use the `AndAlso` operator instead of the `And` operator. By using `And` both conditions will be evaluated. By using `AndAlso` the second condition will only be evaluated if the first returns `true`.

**List(Of FileInfo)**

Instead of returning a `List(Of FileInfo)` you should consider to return an `IEnumerable(Of FileInfo)`.

**Naming**

You shouldn't prefix your variables like `strWorkingPath` or `lstAllFiles`.

**GetFiles() vs EnumerateFiles()**

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx)

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

**Refactoring**

First we will extract the loading of the file and reading the properties to separate methods and add a private class holding the `TypeIndex` and `Version` properties of the xml file.

```
Private Shared Function DoesFileMatch(file As FileInfo, index As String) As Boolean
    Dim version As XmlVersion = GetXmlVersion(file)
    Return (version.Version = "0" AndAlso version.TypeIndex = index)
End Function

Private Shared Function GetXmlVersion(file As FileInfo) As XmlVersion
    Return New XmlVersion(XElement.Load(file.FullName))
End Function

Private Class XmlVersion
    Public Property TypeIndex As String
    Public Property Version As String
    Public Sub New(element As XElement)
        TypeIndex = element.Element("TypeIndex").Value
        Version = element.Element("Version").Value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Next we add an overloaded `GetListByType()` method which takes a `DirectoryInfo` and a `String` as input parameter.

```
Shared Function GetListByType(directory As DirectoryInfo, ByVal typeIndex As String) As IEnumerable(Of FileInfo)

End Function
```

Which we call in our former method like

```
Shared Function GetListByType(ByVal typeIndex As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of FileInfo)
    Return GetListByType(typeIndex.ToString(), New DirectoryInfo(GetWorkspaceDir))
End Function
```

The overloaded method can then be simplified, using all above, to

```
Private Shared Function GetListByType(directory As DirectoryInfo, ByVal typeIndex As String) As IEnumerable(Of FileInfo)

    Dim filteredFiles As New List(Of FileInfo)

    For Each fic In directory.EnumerateFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        If (DoesFileMatch(fic, typeIndex)) Then
            filteredFiles.Add(fic)
        End If
    Next

    Return filteredFiles.Distinct()

End Function
```

But wait, we can do this a lot more `lambda like`

```
Private Shared Function GetListByType(directory As DirectoryInfo, ByVal typeIndex As String) As IEnumerable(Of FileInfo)

    Return directory.EnumerateFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories) _
        .Where(Function(x) DoesFileMatch(x, typeIndex)) _
        .Distinct()

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

I am impressed by the above answer but would like to add some minor things:

You should almost always set [Option Infer On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/bb384665.aspx):

```
Private Shared Function DoesFileMatch(file As FileInfo, index As String) As Boolean
    Dim version = GetXmlVersion(file)
    Return version.Version = "0" AndAlso version.TypeIndex = index
End Function
```

Don't use unnecessary parentheses (that's for C# programmers).